# Error while integration a html template and url in django

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls

I am using `Django` version 1.10.

Below is my `urls.py`(frontend),

```
from django.conf.urls import include,url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
   url(r'^webApp/', include('webApp.urls')),
   url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
   url(r'^home/$', 'frontend.views.home', name='home'),
]
```

Below is my `urls.py`(webApp),

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),

]
```

And below is my `views.py`,

```
def home(request):
    return render_to_response('home.html')
```

Here, `frontend` is my project name and `webApp` is my app name. And i have a `home.html` in my `templates` folder in `frontend`.

When I run,

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

I get the following error,

```
File "/root/frontend/frontend/urls.py", line 22, in <module>
url(r'^home/$', 'frontend.views.home', name='home'),
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/urls/__init__.py", line 85, in url
raise TypeError('view must be a callable or a list/tuple in the case of include().')
TypeError: view must be a callable or a list/tuple in the case of include()
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong... Any guidance in the same?

Comment: Do you have `urls.py` inside `webApp` package?

Comment: Yes i do... I tried commenting and running.. gives the same error...

Comment: import `webApp` in the root `urls.py`

Comment: can you show `webApp.urls` in your post?

Comment: Have added the urls.py for webApp.. Will import webApp in root urls.py and check

Comment: As an aside, don't use `render_to_response`, it's obsolete. Change the import to `from django.shortcuts import render`, and change the view to `return render(request, 'home.html')`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `urlpatterns` list you are not properly using the function `url` (you're passing a string as its second argument, but it - in this case - `[..] must be a callable [..]`).

So... just change `'frontend.views.home'` to `frontend.views.home` (i.e. remove single quotes) and you should be fine.

Comment: You'll have to add an import e.g. `import frontend.views` at the same time.

Comment: @FilippoLauria you are mistaken. Without the import, you'll get an error like `NameError: name 'frontend' is not defined`